# How to add new application to Fabric

Tags: crashlytics, google-fabric, crashlytics-beta

Something has been changed since I added my last application to Fabric because I just can't find how to add a new one. I made this: `Settings` -> `Apps` -> `Add`. The last step redirects me to the [Kits](https://fabric.io/kits) page where I don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Paul from Fabric here. To install a new app, choose the Crashlytics kit and follow the instructions there.

For iOS: https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install

For Android: https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install

Comment: Ahh I see... thank you! So I don't have to add it manually, just simply build the app.

Comment: I had to build/run my android app and Fabric detected the new app connection. I went back to the Dashboard and saw the new app added to Fabric. I just finished the process editing the new app details.

Answer (score 1):

Just plugin in android studio :- **File** > **Setting** > **Plugin** >Search Fabric and click on **Search in repositories** and install it.Restart android studio and click on fabric icon and simple click to add your project.And you have to also apply all code simple click on apply.

Fabric add project:- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ote9wNC8dwk