# Cant add new application to Fabric

Tags: crashlytics, google-fabric

I am trying to add Crashlytics to my new Android app. 
I have followed all of the instructions from this question:

[How to add new application to Fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50314045/how-to-add-new-application-to-fabric)

I created a new Organization on my Fabric profile since it is a team collaboration, and copied the API key from that into my Manifest, but the app doesnt get created. What am I doing wrong?

The app syncs fine, and I dont get any error messages when building.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I'm an idiot. 
I put the code

```
Fabric.with(this, Crashlytics())
```

in my MainActivity since the instructions stated it, but that activity is never called. It's not even added to my manifest.

So obviously the line was never run, and the app was never added.

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually launched the app? That must be done for Fabric to pick it up.

If you've already tried this, I suggest [enabling debugging](https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/advanced-settings/debugging.html) and seeing if any errors are logged:

```
final Fabric fabric = new Fabric.Builder(this)
        .kits(new Crashlytics())
        .debuggable(true)
        .build();
Fabric.with(fabric);
```

Comment: Yes I have launched it multiple times, even crashed it a few times as well, still nothing.
Where should I put the code?